# Populate html table with selected options

Tags: javascript, html

please help me learn. I'd like to learn how to populate the first column of a table with selected options as seen in the following code. Please feel free to use an example of your own if that's easier

```
<html>
<label for="foods">What do you want to eat?</label><br>
<select id="foods" name="foods" size="7" multiple>
  <option value="1">Burrito</option>
  <option value="2">Cheeseburger</option>
  <option value="3">Double Bacon Burger Supreme</option>
  <option value="4">Pepperoni Pizza</option>
  <option value="5">Taco</option>
</select>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>First row</td>
    <td>First row 2nd cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second row</td>
    <td>more stuff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button name="order" id="order" onclick="doTheInsert()">
  Order Now
</button>
<p id="output">
</p>
</html>
<script> 
let itemList = document.getElementById("foods");
let collection = itemList.selectedOptions;
function doTheInsert() {
  var newRow=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow();
  newRow.innerHTML="<td>itemList.selectedOptions</td>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to start with a basic HTML tutorial, as there are syntax issues with your posted code. Furthermore, SO is not a code writing service, we help with written code, where you are supposed to show an effort of your own. Please do, and if you can't make it work, come back with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little edit in script tag

Using an itemList.value return a value of selected options

```
<html>
<label for="foods">What do you want to eat?</label><br>
<select id="foods" name="foods" size="7" multiple>
  <option value="Burrito">Burrito</option>
  <option value="Cheeseburger">Cheeseburger</option>
  <option value="Double Bacon Burger Supreme">Double Bacon Burger Supreme</option>
  <option value="Pepperoni Pizza">Pepperoni Pizza</option>
  <option value="Taco">Taco</option>
</select>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>First row</td>
    <td>First row 2nd cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second row</td>
    <td>more stuff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button name="order" id="order" onclick="doTheInsert()">
  Order Now
</button>
<p id="output">
</p>
</html>
<script> 
let itemList = document.getElementById("foods");
function doTheInsert() {
  var newRow=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow();
  newRow.innerHTML=`<td>${itemList.value}</td>`;
}
</script>
```

Comment: With **`itemList.value`** only you get **the first element** that has been selected,
while whith **`itemList.selectedOptions`** you get a HTMLCollection with items that you have selected.